# Datatables and stateSave : is it possible to save state but not the displayed data?

Tags: datatables

I do use datatables and saveState.

https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/state_save.html

My big problem are data. Since I use ajax to fetch data, the stateSave keeps displaying the SAME data as the first time I connected.

When I remove the stateSave plugin, it shows the good fresh data

My goal would be only to save the columns positions, ordering, but not the data ?

regards

Comment: It is your browsers cache.  Turn caching off in your AJAX connection. `saveState` does not save the data unless you have customised the callbacks to do so.

Comment: No : I see the AJAX result: it retrieves 8 rows  and display just 1 
When I remove the sateSave, it displays the 8 rows.

Comment: It display just 1 row if it has saved a filter that returns one row. You can look for yourself under application -> local storage -> dataTables_something.  Try empty the local storage ....